# angularjs: need to bind input datepicker to params value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

what is wrong with this.  my params do not get the value from my datepicker! I need to have a datepicker input option and I need to send that in angular as a parameter that eventually gets sent to c# paramaeter.

```
<div layout="column">

    <md-content md-primary>
        <md-toolbar layout="flex">
            <button ng-click="toggleSidenav('left')" class="menuBtn">
                <span class="visually-hidden">Menu</span>
            </button>
            <h1>selling Order History</h1>
        </md-toolbar>
        <div layout="row" style="height:100%" flex>
            <md-sidenav layout="column" ng-class="lockedOpen" class="md-closed md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left">
                <div>
                </div>
            </md-sidenav>
            <md-content ng-controller="sellingListCtrl" layout="column" flex class="md-padding">
                <md-tabs class="md-primary clearfix" md-selected="0" flex>              
                    <md-tab label="selling Orders">    

                        <input type="date" ng-model="filter.fromDate" />
                        <input type="date" ng-model="filter.toDate" />

                ...
```

here is the .js file

```
var sellingApp = angular.module('sellingApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ui.router', 'angularMoment', 'breeze.directives', 'breeze.angular', 'ui.bootstrap.pagination']).run(['breeze', function (breeze) { }]);;


sellingApp.controller('sellingListCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$filter', '$location', 'breeze','sellingService',
    function ($scope, $filter, $location, breeze, sellingService) {

        $scope.pageLoaded = true;
        $scope.lists = [];
        $scope.loadselling = function () {
            $scope.pageLoaded = false;
            $scope.filter = {};
            //$scope.filter.fromDate = "1/1/2015";
            //$scope.filter.toDate = "1/1/2015";


            sellingService.salesstatus($scope.filter).then(function (data) {
                $scope.lists = data;
                $scope.totalItems = data.totalItems;
                if (data!=null) {
                    $scope.pageLoaded = true;                      
                }
            });
        }
        //$scope.init();
    }
]);

sellingApp.factory('sellingService', ['$filter','$http', function ($filter, $http) {

    function salesstatus(filter) {
        var f = filter;
        console.log(breeze);

        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/Services/SalesStatus',
            params: { fromDate: f.fromDate, toDate: f.toDate, sParts: true }
        }).then(function (result)
        { return result.data; })

        //.catch(function (s) { console.log(s); });
    }
    return {
        salesstatus: salesstatus

    };
}]);
```

Comment: You should properly format (separate) your code chunks.  Additionally, you should be more clear about the error you're seeing, and maybe list approaches you've tried.

Comment: i made it much shorter and easier to read now.  if i do $scope.filters.fromDate = new Date(); then it works but DOES NOT pull the date from my datepicker.  if i don't do that then i get invalid date and sometimes 500 not found error.  depending on what changes i try.

Comment: That's a good start.  I've improved your formatting further.

Comment: do you know what i'm doing wrong besides formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize `$scope.filter` outside `$scope.loadselling`:

```
sellingApp.controller('sellingListCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$filter', '$location', 'breeze','sellingService',
    function ($scope, $filter, $location, breeze, sellingService) {

        $scope.pageLoaded = true;
        $scope.lists = [];
        $scope.filter = {
           fromDate: '',
           toDate: ''
        };
        $scope.loadselling = function () {
            $scope.pageLoaded = false;

            sellingService.salesstatus($scope.filter).then(function (data) {
                $scope.lists = data;
                $scope.totalItems = data.totalItems;
                if (data!=null) {
                    $scope.pageLoaded = true;                      
                }
            });
        }
        //$scope.init();
    }
]);
```